# phpstorm debugging mamp but not my remote server

Tags: phpstorm

I have tried many ways to debug my remote server but I am unable to do so. My ftp and sftp and remote db is configures to my phpstorm 9 but I cannot debug my remote server it is connecting to my mamp server and debugging ,y local files but not connecting to server username and password . Basically it fails at mysql_connect but works for mamp.How can I make it deubug with server.Everything else is synced with server but I cannot debug. I really appreciate any help.

Edit: Should I install x-debug on my server(cpanel) also ?

php.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php55-xdebug/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

Comment: It's almost impossible to help you given that you did not provide any information about your setup. Please read [this article](http://axiac.ro/blog/2014/03/debugging-remote-php-cli-scripts-with-phpstorm-and-xdebug/) first. You can ignore the "Starting the debugger" sections as you probably want to debug web pages and not CLI scripts. In this case you start the debug session using the IDE. Having the [XDebug](http://xdebug.org) PHP extension installed and loaded is mandatory, of course.

Comment: @axiac I have updated the Q . I have all the above parameters in php.ini file. But its still not working . Also I have 

 

ssh user@remote-host -R 9000:localhost:9000

Comment: Am I missing something .I am on it from last 2 days.Please let me know.

Comment: Also I did not get “PHP_IDE_CONFIG" .How should I do it ?

Comment: The variable `PHP_IDE_CONFIG` is also needed only for CLI scripts. Ignore it. For web pages you should use the "Web Server Debug Validation" tool (it's the last entry in the "Run" menu). It helps you find out if the server is properly configured for PHP debugging. I hope the excerpt from `php.ini` you posted is from the web server you want to use and not from localhost.

Comment: php.ini is from localhost. Should I install it on server ??

Comment: [XDebug](http://xdebug.org) is a PHP extension. It must be installed and loaded by the PHP on the same server where PHP runs. If you want to debug the code running on the remote server then you need PHP installed on the remote server and also the XDebug extension installed and properly configured on the remote server too. It is the link between the PHP interpreter (which runs the code) and the debug client (PhpStorm in this case).

Comment: So the above xdebug code should be added on server php ?

Comment: I don't have any permission to install it on server. sudo is not working. Any ideas ??

Comment: You can debug the code on your local computer. It probably cannot connect to the database; you need to use cPanel to create an user that can connect from the IP address of you local computer. If the local computer doesn't have a fixed IP address but you can ssh into the webserver then you can create a ssh tunnel (ssh user@webserver -L 3306:database_server:3306) and use "localhost" in the configuration file as database host.

Comment: SO you dont have to add the code above on the server? only ssh is enough??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understand your question/problem. These are the ways you can debug your code

#### Debug the local code that uses the local database

This is the easiest setup and it probably already works on your system. You have all the files on the local computer and also you have an instance of MySQL running on it. The code connects to `localhost:3306`, the `xdebug` extension is installed and it can connect to `PhpStorm`, everybody is happy.

#### Debug the local code that uses the remote database

You can have all the PHP files on `localhost` and use the local `mamp` stack to debug it; you control the environment, `xdebug` works and happily collaborates with `PhpStorm`. You want the code to be able to use the remote (live) database.

In this case you need a way to access the database. Either you create a `MySQL` user that allows you to connect from the IP address of the local computer (a firewall along the way might prevent this), or start a `ssh` session that creates a tunnel from the local port `3306` (or any other open port you choose) to port `3306` of the database server (assuming the host where you ssh is allowed to connect to it). You can do this by running

```
ssh user@remote_host -L 3306:database_host:3306
```

*(replace `user`, `remote_host` and `database_host` with your actual values)*

If you have a MySQL server installed and running on `localhost` then the local port `3306` is not open and `ssh` cannot use it as the source port of the tunnel. Use another port instead (let's say you use 13306):

```
ssh user@remote_host -L 13306:database_host:3306
```

Modify the local configuration files of your application to use `localhost` as database server and `13306` as database port.

#### Debug the remote code

If you want to debug the live code (it uses the live database) then you have to upload the code on the web server (the live environment) and make it work there (be able to connect to the database etc).

In order to be able to debug it you need to have the `xdebug` PHP extension installed on the server and properly configured in the server's `php.ini` configuration file.

The debugger (the remote `xdebug` extension) needs to connect to your local computer where `PhpStorm` is listening on port `9000`. This is either impossible or making it happen requires changing configuration here and there in several places (that might be out of your control); we better forget about it.

We can use the ssh tunnel trick: start a ssh connection to the server that creates a tunnel from local port `9000` to the servers port `9000`:

```
ssh user@remote_host -L 9000:localhost:9000
```

#### Test if it works

`PhpStorm` provides a tool that uploads a script on the web server then tries to access it to check if the `xdebug` extension is properly configured. Depending on the version of `PhpStorm` you use, you can find it either in the menu (`Run` -> `Web Server Debug Validation`, on `PhpStorm 9`) or somewhere in the `Settings` (`PHP` -> `Servers` or around, on older versions).